# Manipulating a dynamically loaded table

Tags: jquery

I have a table I manipulate with jQuery, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/tuurester/eow3x2w5/ That part is all fine and working as it's supposed to.

I add that table to a page via via jQuery's `load` function, like so:

```
$('#matrixclicker').click(function(){
    $('#matrixwrapper').load('matrix.php');
}

$('#matrix-table').on("click", ".matrix-table-chooser", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('matrix-table-chooser');
    $(this).addClass('matrix-table-chosen');
});

$('#matrix-table').on("click", ".matrix-table-chosen", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('matrix-table-chosen');
    $(this).addClass('matrix-table-chooser');
});
```

The table loads to the page with no problems, but I can no longer manipulate it using jQuery, i.e. the functionality to change the cells' class values works no more. After reading a plethora of related questions here on stackoverflow, I was under the impression that using `on("click", function())` would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to.

What am I missing?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#matrixclicker', function() {});` do the trick. It's called event delegation. See more: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using delegated event handler, which is correct, however the primary selector needs to be an element available in the DOM when the page loads. This is why selecting the table doesn't work; it's appended to the DOM after you attempt to add the event handlers.

To fix this, change the selector to be the `#matrixwrapper` instead. Also note that you can join both event handlers together and use `toggleClass()` to simplify the logic.

```
$('#matrixwrapper').on("click", ".matrix-table-chooser, .matrix-table-chosen", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('matrix-table-chooser matrix-table-chosen');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it thoroughly! This will leave the guess work out if it in the future.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.